# Why can I access only some UI control properties from BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker, ui-thread

I have a simple Windows Forms app that uses a couple [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) elements to, well, do things in the background. While developing, I noticed I was able to do things such as get and set the `.Text` value of a Label in the `DoWork()` method, but am not able to get the value of a DrowDownList.

**I was under the impression that the BackgroundWorker is not supposed to have any UI interactions, are there some exceptions to this rule?**

I'm not looking for suggestions to update the UI from the BackgroundWorker, I am more curious if there are shortcuts I can take, like updating the text of a ToolStripStatusLabel directly from the BackgroundWorker.

Here is a simple example, worker 1 updates UI directly while worker 2 uses progress updates:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Performing task 1...";
    performTaskOne();
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Task 1 done.";

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Performing task 2...";
    performTaskTwo();
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Task 2 done.";

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Performing task 3...";
    performTaskThree();
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Task 3 done.";
}

private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, "Performing task 1...");
    performTaskOne();
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(20, "Task 1 done.");

    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(40, "Performing task 2...");
    performTaskTwo();
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(60, "Task 2 done.");

    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(80, "Performing task 3...");
    performTaskThree();
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(100, "Task 3 done.");
}

private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string status = (string)e.UserState;
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = status;
}

private void performTaskThree()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void performTaskTwo()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void performTaskOne()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: happened the same to me, had to use delegates.. but i don't know why +1

Comment: any example code? I don't think there is a limit here, `BackgroundWorker` is just some kind of `lightweight` thread...

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is meant to be UI friendly, but it's still a background thread, meaning that you need to do thread-safe things like use delegates to operate on the UI controls.  Shortcuts often come back to bite you...hard.

Comment: added a code example to illustrate the two approaches

Comment: @invertigo I tested the code and the `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text` is updated OK. What is actually your problem? No exception at all?

Comment: @KingKing no exception, simply trying to determine the proper approach to take (updating from UI thread vs non-UI thread)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing or updating the UI from a background thread.  Period.

It's a *feature* of most UI elements that they will detect if they are not being access from the UI thread and aggressively throw an exception so that the developer becomes immediately aware the first time the code runs that they are accessing the control improperly.

Not all UI controls, and not all aspects of UI controls, have this *feature*.  Certain members are specifically documented as a member of the object that is safe to use from a non-UI thread (for example the `Invoke` method of a control can obviously be used from a non-UI thread; that's why it exists).  For those not documented as such, you should not be using them in non-UI threads.

Just because it doesn't crash the first time you use it doesn't mean it will work.  What it means is that there are likely race conditions throughout the code that can crop up depending on what other threads are accessing shared resources at the same time.  It may work when you test it, it might work repeatedly, but if just the right set of circumstances take place, all sorts of bad things can happen.  Perhaps the program will crash, perhaps data will be corrupted, perhaps things just won't work, or perhaps all sorts of weird and cooky things will happen.  If such code gets set out to clients where you all of a sudden get a lot of different people executing the code in a lot of different and unexpected ways, as well as on very different types of environments, the chances of running into problems not encountered in your own tests goes up dramatically.

So take the time to ensure that you only access UI controls from the UI thread.

It's also worth noting, on an entirely separate note, that it greatly helps to organize your code to have your UI and presentation logic separated from your business logic; mixing them results in applications that are harder to reason about, understand, maintain, or change.